# Initialization order of final fields

Tags: java, constructor, final, jls

Consider these two classes:

```
public abstract class Bar {
    protected Bar() {
        System.out.println(getValue());
    }

    protected abstract int getValue();
}

public class Foo extends Bar {
    private final int i = 20;

    public Foo() {
    }

    @Override
    protected int getValue() {
        return i;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Foo();
    }
}
```

If I execute Foo, the output is 20.

If I make the field non-final, or if I initialize it in the Foo constructor, the output is 0.

My question is: what is the initialization order in case of final fields and where is this behavior described in the JLS?

I expected to find some exceptional rule about final fields [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5), but unless I miss something, there isn't.

Note that I know I should never call an overridable method from a constructor. That's not the point of the question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your `final int i` member variable is a constant variable: [4.12.4. `final` Variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4)

> A variable of primitive type or type `String`, that is `final` and initialized with a compile-time constant expression (§15.28), is called a *constant variable*.

This has consequences for the order in which things are initialized, as described in  [12.4.2. Detailed Initialization Procedure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2).

Comment: Had to remove my comment about `final int` being a *compile time constant* (had no *supporting evidence*.. Was looking for this answer.. Thank you). +1 :P..

Comment: Good point. I missed this "constant variable" reference (what an oxymoron!). But I still don't fully grasp what that changes in the object initialization procedure. When is this constant variable assigned? The detailed initialization procedure talks about class initialization, and talks about the initialization of "final class variables", but not about the initialization of "final instance variables" (unless I miss something again).

Comment: OK. I found it. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.2 says: "Some expressions have a value that can be determined at compile time. These are constant expressions (§15.28).". And http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28 says that "Simple names (§6.5.6.1) that refer to constant variables (§4.12.4)" are constant expressions. So `i` in `getValue()` is a simple name referring to a constant variable, and its value is thus known at compile-time.

Comment: The link to the  “Detailed Initialization Procedure“ is a bit misleading as it describes the class initialization, in other words, is relevant to `static` fields only. In fact, `final` instance fields are assigned just like other fields, but the relevant point is that `getValue()` never reads the field, but just returns the constant value.

Answer (score 5):

Walking you through how this looks in a "byte-code-ish" way.

You should already be aware, that the first actual instruction in a constructor must be a call to `super` (whether with arguments or without).

That super instruction returns when the parent constructor is finished and the super "object" is fully constructed. So when you construct `Foo` the following happens (in order):

```
// constant fields are initialized by this point
Object.construction // constructor call of Object, done by Bar
Bar.construction // aka: Foo.super()
callinterface getValue() // from Bar constructor
// this call is delegated to Foo, since that's the actual type responsible
// and i is returned to be printed
Foo.construction
```

if you were to initialize it in the constructor, that would happen "now", after `getValue()` had already been called.

Comment: I know that, but that doesn't explain why i has the value 20 when the field is final and 0 when it's not.

Comment: JB hmm... well I don't really want to steal Jesper's good answer

Comment: When I read the JVM spec, it required that no code which could be reached before the parent constructor call could do anything with the object under construction *except for storing values to derived-class fields*.  Exception-handling constructs which could bypass a parent constructor were forbidden, though I don't remember what exact rules were used (e.g. if any code which was reachable via an exception that could be thrown before the parent constructor completed would be deemed as running without the parent constructor having been called).

Comment: IMHO, the Java language (and many .NET languages as well) are a little anemic with regard to construction chaining.  There are many situations where `foo=new Bar();` cannot perform its duties without using virtual methods, but there's no nice pattern by which `Bar` can let derived classes examine their passed-in parameters before exercising its one and only opportunity to ensure that its duties get completed.  Perhaps the cleanest approach would be to have some constructors which are *only* for construction of `Bar` objects (and which no *legitimate* derived class is allowed to chain to)...

Comment: ...and have other constructors which are only supposed to be used to construct derived objects (which would in turn be expected to follow the same pattern themselves).  Unfortunately, I know of no mechanism for `Bar` specify that a constructor should be public for code that wants to construct `Bar` instances, but should not be usable for constructing the `Bar` portion of `DerivedBar` instances.